# Why Does My Script Hang When I Run The Timer To Call Back The Method ? Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why Does my Script Hang when I Run My Timer ? and when the Timer Stop, It will call back the method.

For example my code below :

> Script File - LakeSpot.cs (This script is generate random the spot
>   Like Easy Spot, Very Easy Spot, and soon)

**I have shorten the code and delete the same code.**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class LakeSpot : MonoBehaviour {
    player Player;
    fishingDatabase fishDatabase;
    Image itemImage;
    Sprite icon;
    int maxSpot = 5;
    List<spawnSpot> spot = new List<spawnSpot>();
    int k = 0;
    int maxVES;
    int index;
    getSpotLakeScript spotscript;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("player").GetComponent<player> ();
        fishDatabase = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("fishingDatabase").GetComponent<fishingDatabase> ();

        index = fishDatabase.spawnRateLake.FindIndex (j => j.Level == spawnSpot.spotLevel.VES);
        maxVES = fishDatabase.spawnRateLake [index].maxSpawn;


            GenerateSpot ();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void GenerateSpot() {
            Player.lakerollFishing = new List<int> ();
            Player.lakeSpotRoll = new List<int> ();
            Player.lakeNotActiveSpot = new List<int> ();
        for(int i = 0; i < maxSpot; i++) {
            int roll = Random.Range(0,fishDatabase.spawnRateLake.Count);
            if(fishDatabase.spawnRateLake[roll].Level == spawnSpot.spotLevel.VES) {
                if(maxVES > 0) {
                    this.gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    icon = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("spotLevel" + "/" + "Very Easy Spot");
                    itemImage = this.gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Image>();
                    itemImage.sprite = icon;

                    maxVES--;
                    Player.lakerollFishing.Add(roll);
                    Player.lakeSpotRoll.Add(i);
                } else {
                    i--;
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

The methode GenereratSpot() is for generate randomly spot Like Very Easy Spot, Easy Spot, and soon

> And Then i Have the script file - LakeVisitTimer.cs (This Script is
>   for countdown the timer. When Timer is zero that it will call the
>   GenerateSpot() method again.

**I have shorten the code.**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class LakeVisitTimer : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text TimerText;
    public string dy;
    public float days;
    public float Hours;
    public float Minutes;
    public float Seconds;
    int code;

    LakeSpot spots;
    player Player;
    GameObject lakeside;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () { 
        StartCoroutine(Wait());
    }

    void Awake() {
        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("player").GetComponent<player> ();
        lakeside = GameObject.Find ("LakeSide").gameObject;
        spots = lakeside.gameObject.transform.GetChild (1).GetComponent<LakeSpot>();

        code = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("LakeVisitCode");
        if (code == 1) {
            OnResumeSession ();
        }
    }

    public void StopTimer() {
        Seconds = 0;
        Minutes = 0;
        Hours = 0;
        days = 0;
        Player.maxLakeFishing = 2;
        Player.lakerollFishing = new List<int> ();
        Player.lakeSpotRoll = new List<int> ();
        Player.lakeNotActiveSpot = new List<int> ();

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LakeVisitCode",0);
        spots.GenerateSpot ();
    }

}
```

The Method StopTimer() is work when Timer is Zero. And It call back the spots.GenerateSpot() which is a method from LakeSpot.cs where function used to Generate randomly spot.

For Example the timer is zero now and it call back the GenerateSpot(). When call back it become Hang.

And I check the Task Manager the memory Take until 300 MB.

What is going on ?

Comment: **"Script Hang when I Run My Timer"** Where is the run timer code? Why not put `Debug.Log` everywhere if you don't know how to use the Debugger  and tell us where the script freezes. It does somewhere but no ones knows.

Comment: Hi @Programmer, the script timer code is on LakeVisitTimer.cs. That is a script timer. But i shorten the code. I just show you the method that call back the the other method

Comment: @Programmer, i think i have find the problem. The problem is at LakeSpot.cs script in generateSpot() there is : Player.lakerollFishing = new List<int> ();
      Player.lakeSpotRoll = new List<int> ();
      Player.lakeNotActiveSpot = new List<int> (); and in LakeVisitTimer.cs script in the StopTimer() method also have that script. When i remove it from LakeSpot.cs In Method GenerateSpot() it run successfull. I think The problem is at there. Now it work

Comment: So your problem is fixed?

Comment: Yes.. it is fixed now.. Thank You. I think i must post my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I just removed the script :

```
Player.lakerollFishing = new List<int> ();
 Player.lakeSpotRoll = new List<int> ();
 Player.lakeNotActiveSpot = new List<int> ();
```

from LakeSpot.cs at GenerateSpot() method

That script I have already call it LakeVisitTimer.cs at method StopTimer().